# Suggestions on a macro that reads data from an Excel sheet and writes to a pre-defined File via Replace and FileSystemObject

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a VBA macro that should read some data from an Excel sheet and then handle this data to create a XML file which I'll use on another application.
Simply put, I have 3 source .txt files, 2 of them have placeholders (eg. NAMEXXX) that I replace with the sheet data and the last .txt file is the destination of the other 2, which is saved as .XML.
I'd like some suggestions on how I could make my code better or more optimized, once I'm not vey familiar with VBA functions. Here are the 3 functions I've written:

```
Public Function ReplaceCardInfo(contDI As Integer)
    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim NomeCartaoDI As Variant
    Dim Endereco As Variant
    Dim i, j As Integer

    ReDim NomeCartaoDI(1 To contDI)
    ReDim Endereco(1 To contDI)

    For j = 1 To contDI
        Sheet2.Cells(j, 6).Select 'card name
        aux = ActiveCell.Value
        NomeCartaoDI(j) = aux
        Sheet2.Cells(j, 13).Select 'adress
        aux = ActiveCell.Value
        Endereco(j) = Mid(aux, 3, 1) 'in the sheet, data is 'I 0.5' and I only need the 0
    Next j
    'Now, I open the pre defined file containing placeholders to be replaced
    sFileName = "C:\CardModel.xml"
    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close iFileNum

    For i = 1 To contDI
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "NAMEXXX", NomeCartaoDI(i))
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "ADDRXXX", Endereco(i))
    Next i
    'Now I save the new file with the replaced data
    iFileNum = FreeFile
    sFileName = "C:\CardName.txt"
    Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
    Print #iFileNum, sTemp
    Close iFileNum
    End Function
```

The above function replaces sheet info in one of the .txt source files

```
    Public Function ReplaceTagTable()

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim IName As Variant
    Dim IReplaceName As Variant
    Dim aux As Variant
    Dim iSubA As Long
    Dim jSubA As Long

    IName = Sheet2.Range("A1:A16").Value        'data I want to write to the .txt file
    IReplaceName = Sheet2.Range("O2:O17").Value 'placeholders to be replaced eg NAMEXXX
    'Now, I open the pre defined file containing placeholders to be replaced
    sFileName = "D:\Exportados\TESTE_01.ap16\TESTE_01\DigitalIO.txt"
    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close iFileNum
    'Here I walk through the file to replace the placeholders
    For iSubA = 1 To UBound(IName, 1)
       sTemp = Replace(sTemp, IReplaceName(iSubA, 1), IName(iSubA, 1))
    Next iSubA
    'Now I save the new file with the replaced data
    iFileNum = FreeFile
    sFileName = "C:\DigitalIOReplaced.txt"
    Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
    Print #iFileNum, sTemp
    Close iFileNum
    End Function
```

The above function replaces data to another .txt file

```
    Public Function EscreveAML()
    Dim TextString As Variant
        'read text from file
    TextString = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile _
    ("C:\REPLACE3_TestDI.txt").ReadAll, _
    Chr(13) & Chr(10)) 'lê o arquivo modelo a ser exportado
        'change your text here as TextString(#Line - 1) = "Text"
    TextString(63) = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile _
    ("C:\DigitalIOReplaced.txt").ReadAll
    Dim i As Integer
        'Here I walk through the file to find the line where I write the CardName.txt file
    Do Until (TextString(i) = "<!--Card Name Here-->") 
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    TextString(i + 1) = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile _
    ("C:\CardName.txt").ReadAll    
        'Here I save the new file as FinalFile.xml
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile _
    ("C:\FinalFile.xml").Write (Join(TextString, Chr(13) & Chr(10)))
    End Function
```

The above function reads the last .txt file, writes the content of the files created by the first and second functions and creates the complete XML file.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Also, I'd like to know how the sheet I want to be read can be passed as an argument of these functions, because that would make the macro soft coded.

Comment: Your first function can be improved putting the range to be processed in an array (`arr = Sheet2.Range("F1:M" & contDI).value` then  iterate between the array elements (much faster than in the range), without select anything. Use `arr(i, 1)` and `arr(i, 8)`. Then, put `sFileName` content at once (in a variable) and use `Replace` on this one, also at once. In the second function, read also at once the text file content and iterate between arrays elements to replace the strings they contain.

Comment: `sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "NAMEXXX", NomeCartaoDI(i))` doesnt this just replace all "NAMEXXX" with only the first element in `NomeCartaDI` ?

Comment: I'd start by abstracting out your text file read/write into two standalone methods, then standardize on *one* replacement method (right now it seems like you have 3 different methods: fixed line number, text token replacement, and a line "marker" to indicate the next line is to be replaced)  Standardizing would be easier to manage, and allow you to create some "helper" methods which would keep your main code much shorter and easier to maintain.

Comment: @FaneDuru, Thanks for the array improvement, it will be quite useful. However, I couldn't figure out what you've meant with "put sFileName content at once (in a variable) and use Replace on this one". How'd I do that? Instead of using sTemp I'd use `Replace(sFileName, "FIRMXXX", IFirmware(i))` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks for your answers. The observation you made is correct, I used to replace by iteration but it's not necessary anymore. About the replacement standard, I don't believe it's possible because while the text token is a normal replacement, the line marker is used to join one big text file into another. However, the fixed line number is truly unecessary. Thanks for the insight

Comment: No, you should use a similar method with the one used in the last function. Something like `sTemp= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\CardModel.xml").ReadAll`. Then, already having `sTemp` you can use your existing code, saving the time necessary to iterate between the file lines...

Comment: Joining one file into another could also be done using token replacement though?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, it could. But my solution must be capable of joining the files multiple times, and that would be impossible if I replace the token at the first code execution. Do you agree?

Comment: Not if you use `Replace(theContent, "<!--Token-->", "<!--Token-->" & vbcrlf & extraContent)`   That can be run as many times as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write text files and then read them, just return the text from the function. Change folder to `C:\` or `D:\Exportados\TESTE_01.ap16\TESTE_01\` as required.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub EscreveAML()

    Dim sFile As String, folder As String, sXML As String, s As String
    Dim infile As String, outfile As String

    sFile = "REPLACE3_TestDI.txt"
    Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object
    folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.opentextfile(folder & sFile)
    
    Do While ts.AtEndOfStream <> True
        s = ts.readline
        If ts.Line = 64 Then

            ' insert text from DigitalIOReplaced.txt
            infile = folder & "DigitalIO.txt"
            outfile = folder & "DigitalIOReplaced.txt"
            sXML = sXML & ReplaceTagTable(FSO, Sheet2, infile, outfile)

        ElseIf InStr(s, "<!--Card Name Here-->") Then
            sXML = sXML & s & vbCrLf

            ' insert text from CardName.txt
            infile = folder & "CardModel.xml"
            outfile = folder & "CardName.txt"
            sXML = sXML & ReplaceCardInfo(FSO, Sheet1, infile, outfile, 5)

        Else
            sXML = sXML & s & vbCrLf
        End If
    Loop

    ' create XML file
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(folder & "FinalFile.xml")
    ts.write sXML
    ts.Close

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Public Function ReplaceCardInfo(FSO As Object, ws As Worksheet, _
           infile As String, outfile As String, _
           contDI As Integer) As String

    Dim ts, s As String, sXML As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim NomeCartaoDI As Variant, Endereco As Variant
    ReDim NomeCartaoDI(1 To contDI)
    ReDim Endereco(1 To contDI)

    ' names and adresses
    For i = 1 To contDI
        NomeCartaoDI(i) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value2 '  col F
        Endereco(i) = Mid(ws.Cells(i, 13).Value2, 3, 1) ' col M
    Next

    ' read in tmplate replacing names
    Set ts = FSO.opentextfile(infile)
    i = 1
    j = 1
    Do While ts.AtEndOfStream <> True
        s = ts.readline
        If InStr(s, "NAMEXXX") Then
           s = Replace(s, "NAMEXXX", NomeCartaoDI(i))
           i = i + 1
        ElseIf InStr(s, "ADDRXXX") Then
           s = Replace(s, "ADDRXXX", Endereco(j))
           j = j + 1
        End If
        sXML = sXML & s & vbCrLf
    Loop
    ts.Close
    
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(outfile)
    ts.write sXML
    ts.Close
    
    ReplaceCardInfo = sXML
End Function

Public Function ReplaceTagTable(FSO, ws As Worksheet, _
         infile As String, outfile As String) As String

    Dim arData, arPlaceHolder, ts, s As String, i As Long
    arData = ws.Range("A1").Resize(16).Value2
    arPlaceHolder = ws.Range("O2").Resize(16).Value2
   
    ' read in template
    Set ts = FSO.opentextfile(infile)
    s = ts.readAll
    ts.Close

    ' replace placeholders
    For i = 1 To UBound(arData)
        s = Replace(s, arPlaceHolder(i, 1), arData(i, 1))
    Next i
   
    ' write out file
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(outfile)
    ts.write s
    ts.Close

    ' return string
    ReplaceTagTable = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with generic functions where possible:

```vb
Public Function ReplaceTagTable()

    PutContent "C:\DigitalIOReplaced.txt", _
               ReplaceTokens(GetContent("D:\Exportados\TESTE_01.ap16\TESTE_01\DigitalIO.txt"), _
                             Sheet2.Range("A1:A16").Value, Sheet2.Range("O2:O17").Value)
               
End Function


'---------------generic methods below here-----------------

Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 1).readall()
End Function

Sub PutContent(f As String, Content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 2, True).write Content
End Sub

'Replace each value in `Tokens` with corresponding value in `Values`
'  `Tokens` and `Values` are 2D arrays as read from a worksheet using Range.Value
Function ReplaceTokens(Content As String, Tokens, Values) As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rv As String
    rv = Content
    For r = 1 To UBound(Tokens, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(Tokens, 2)
        rv = Replace(rv, Tokens(r, c), Values(r, c))
    Next c
    Next r
    ReplaceTokens = rv
End Function
```